# logear con una clave encryption md5 en php

Tags: php

necesito descifrar para poder iniciar sesión, en la web guarde con una encryption md5

```
<?php include 'config2.php';

$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);

    $email = $obj['email'];

    $password = md5($obj['password']);

    if($obj['email']!=""){

    $result= $db->query("SELECT * FROM estudiante where NombreUsuario='$email' and Clave='$password'");

        if($result->num_rows==0){
            echo json_encode('Wrong Details');
        }
        else{
        echo json_encode('ok');
        }
    }
    else{
      echo json_encode('try again');
    }

?>
```

estoy intentado entrar y me da error de contrase;a

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Comprobastes que en tu abse de datos el campo clave tenga el mismo valor que cuando encriptas con md5 lo que traes de php://input???

Comment: el valor de la data base si esta encriptada

Comment: Imprimí el sql que estás ejecutando a ver si los valores son correctos. Por otro lado para que tengas en cuenta: MD5 no es encriptado, es hasheado, y para claves de usuario es un algoritmo debil. El sql que estás ejecutando es vulnerable a sql injection. Usar Prepared Statements para evitar esto último.

Comment: ¿Es en "estudiante.clave" el lugar donde guardas tu clave? Parece que no está en md5. Deberías poner el código que usas para hashear la contraseña. Otro punto: una vez que soluciones tu problema cambia a otro algoritmo para proteger tus contraseñas (como blowfish) pues md5 es obsoleto.

Answer (score 0):

solo en caso de que puedas modificar un registro de tu base de datos, tal vez podrias hacer algo como hashear una palabra cualquier en un archivo php y luego cambiar esa palabra hasheada en un registro de tu base de datos.

Algo asi :

```
 <?php
  $var = md5("cualquierPalabra");
  echo $var;
 ?>
```

ejecutas el script php y lo copias y modificas en uno de tus registros en tu base de datos. Ojo solo en caso de que tengas privilegios para modificar registros en tu base de datos. Alguna vez me toco hacerlo y me funciono xD, una solucion un tanto obsoleta pero bueno, por lo menos en el caso mio  me funciono.